# google maps scaleControlOptions changing position of scale on map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, html5-canvas

I noticed that there was no option to change the position of the scale on google maps using scaleControlOptions (correct me if I'm wrong) and was wondering if there was any way to get around that and display the scale on the bottom left position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification):

> `scaleControl` enables/disables the Scale control that provides a simple
>   map scale. By default, this control is not visible. When enabled, it
>   will always appear in the **bottom right corner** of the map.

So unfortunately, you won't be able to put it in the bottom left position.

Comment: Yep, I saw that too yesterday too. Oh well

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the built in options unfortunately, but you *can* do it with some simple CSS:

```
.gm-bundled-control-on-bottom {
    right: auto !important;
    left: 25px;
}
```

Not sure whether this goes against their TOS but it works.